# Packet Read\Write

Tags: c#

Is this a good method to Read\Write packets

```
using System.Text;

namespace namespace
{
    public unsafe class DataPacket
    {
        public DataPacket(byte[] buffer)
        {
            _buffer = new byte[buffer.Length];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, _buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        public DataPacket(ushort size, ushort type)
        {
            _buffer = new byte[size];
            WriteUInt16(size, 0);
            WriteUInt16(type, 2);
        }

        private readonly byte[] _buffer;
        protected byte[] Buffer
        {
            get
            {
                return _buffer;
            }
        }

        public byte* Ptr
        {
            get
            {
                fixed (byte* ptr = Buffer)
                    return ptr;
            }
        }

        public ushort Size
        {
            get
            {
                return ReadUInt16(0);
            }
            set
            {
                WriteUInt16(value, 0);
            }
        }

        public ushort Type
        {
            get
            {
                return ReadUInt16(2);
            }
            set
            {
                WriteUInt16(value, 2);
            }
        }

        public void WriteSByte(sbyte value, int offset)
        {
            (*(sbyte*)(Ptr + offset)) = value;
        }
        public void WriteInt16(short value, int offset)
        {
            (*(short*)(Ptr + offset)) = value;
        }
        public void WriteInt32(int value, int offset)
        {
            (*(int*)(Ptr + offset)) = value;
        }
        public void WriteInt64(long value, int offset)
        {
            (*(long*)(Ptr + offset)) = value;
        }
        public void WriteByte(byte value, int offset)
        {
            (*(Ptr + offset)) = value;
        }
        public void WriteUInt16(ushort value, int offset)
        {
            (*(ushort*)(Ptr + offset)) = value;
        }
        public void WriteUInt32(uint value, int offset)
        {
            (*(uint*)(Ptr + offset)) = value;
        }
        public void WriteUInt64(ulong value, int offset)
        {
            (*(ulong*)(Ptr + offset)) = value;
        }
        public void WriteStringWithLength(string value, int offset, out int nextoffset)
        {
            WriteByte((byte)(value.Length > 255 ? 255 : value.Length), offset);
            offset++;

            foreach (var c in value)
            {
                WriteByte((byte)c, offset);
                offset++;
            }
            nextoffset = offset;
        }
        public void WriteString(string value, int offset)
        {
            foreach (var c in value)
            {
                WriteByte((byte)c, offset);
                offset++;
            }
        }

        public sbyte ReadSByte(int offset)
        {
            return (*(sbyte*)(Ptr + offset));
        }
        public short ReadInt16(int offset)
        {
            return (*(short*)(Ptr + offset));
        }
        public int ReadInt32(int offset)
        {
            return (*(int*)(Ptr + offset));
        }
        public long ReadInt64(int offset)
        {
            return (*(long*)(Ptr + offset));
        }
        public byte ReadByte(int offset)
        {
            return (*(Ptr + offset));
        }
        public byte[] ReadBytes(int offset, int length)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            for (var i = offset; i < length; i++)
                bytes[i] = (*(Ptr + i));
            return bytes;
        }
        public ushort ReadUInt16(int offset)
        {
            return (*(ushort*)(Ptr + offset));
        }
        public uint ReadUInt32(int offset)
        {
            return (*(uint*)(Ptr + offset));
        }
        public ulong ReadUInt64(int offset)
        {
            return (*(ulong*)(Ptr + offset));
        }
        public string ReadString(int offset, int length)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
                sb.Append((char)ReadByte(offset + i));
            return sb.ToString().Replace("\0", "").Replace("\r", "");
        }
        public string ReadString(int offset)
        {
            var size = ReadByte(offset);
            offset++;
            return ReadString(offset, size);
        }

        public byte[] ToArray()
        {
            var newbuffer = new byte[Buffer.Length];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Buffer, 0, newbuffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
            return newbuffer;
        }

        public static implicit operator byte[](DataPacket dPacket)
        {
            return dPacket.ToArray();
        }

        public static implicit operator DataPacket(byte[] packet)
        {
            return new DataPacket(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

At first glance, I can see several problem with this code (why are you even using pointers? what happens with non-ASCII characters in `WriteString()`?). But my main issue is that [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) and [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) do something very similar, so you're kind of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I always prefer using pointers its just a prefer :D even i use memory copy instead of Buffer.BlockCopy.
Also could you provide me with an edited code with what you expect it to be ?

Comment: Well, I would expect you to use the two classes instead of `DataPacket`, so there is no code to show.

Comment: BinaryWriter is working with stream, not with buffer

Comment: Yeah, but you can use `MemoryStream`, which is just a `Stream` wrapper around a `byte[]`.